# OpenGL (big) pictures are hatched with green lines

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm using OpenGL for display YUV420P frames on screen in Android.
With some resolution, my frame looks good, but with big resolution (on the same screen), it still looks like my original frame (with colors and all), but with some green lines hatching it (depending to the orientation, 4 lines, 30 lines?).

Here is an example (an 1080x607 frame):

[image]

Is it a alignment problem? A texture binding problem? Here is my code:

```
private final short[] INDICES_DATA = {0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};

private final float[] VERTICES_DATA = new float[] {
    -1f, 1f, 0f,
    0f, 0f,
    -1f, -1f, 0f,
    0f, 1f,
    1f, -1f, 0f,
    1f, 1f,
    1f, 1f, 0f,
    1f, 0f
};

private final String szVertexShaderCode =
        "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
        "attribute vec2 aTexCoord;\n" +
        "varying vec2 vTexCoord;\n" +

        "void main() {\n" +
        "   gl_Position = aPosition;\n" +
        "   vTexCoord = aTexCoord;\n" +
        "}\n";

private final String szYUV420PFragmentShaderCode =
        "#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH\n" +
        "   precision highp float;\n" +
        "#else\n" +
        "   precision mediump float;\n" +
        "#endif\n" +

        "varying vec2 vTexCoord;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D yTexture;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D uTexture;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D vTexture;\n" +

        "void main() {\n" +
        "   float r, g, b, y, u, v;\n" +

        "   y = texture2D(yTexture, vTexCoord).r;\n" +
        "   u = texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoord).r - 0.5;\n" +
        "   v = texture2D(vTexture, vTexCoord).r - 0.5;\n" +

        "   r = y + (1.13983 * v);\n" +
        "   g = y - (0.39465 * u) - (0.58060 * v);\n" +
        "   b = y + (2.03211 * u);\n" +

        "   gl_FragColor = vec4(r, g, b, 1.0);\n" +
        "}\n";
```

**Function on surface created:**

```
    //initShadersAndProgram();

    iPositionLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(iProgram, "aPosition");
    iTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(iProgram, "aTexCoord");

    // Is this line useful?
    GLES20.glPixelStorei(GLES20.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    iYTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgram, "yTexture");
    int[] yTextureNames = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, yTextureNames, 0);
    int iYTextureName = yTextureNames[0];
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, iYTextureName);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    iUTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgram, "uTexture");
    int[] uTextureNames = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, uTextureNames, 0);
    int iUTextureName = uTextureNames[0];
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, iUTextureName);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    iVTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgram, "vTexture");
    int[] vTextureNames = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, vTextureNames, 0);
    int iVTextureName = vTextureNames[0];
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE3);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, iVTextureName);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

**Function on draw frame:**

```
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

GLES20.glUseProgram(iProgram);

verticesBuffer.position(0);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iPositionLoc, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, verticesBuffer);

verticesBuffer.position(3);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, verticesBuffer);

GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(iPositionLoc);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(iTexCoordLoc);

GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);

GLES20.glUniform1i(iYTexture, 1);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
        pixmap.getWidth(),
        pixmap.getHeight(),
        0,
        GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
        GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        /* buffer Y */);

GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2);

GLES20.glUniform1i(iUTexture, 2);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
        pixmap.getWidth() / 2,
        pixmap.getHeight() / 2,
        0,
        GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
        GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        /* buffer U */);

GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE3);

GLES20.glUniform1i(iVTexture, 3);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
        pixmap.getWidth() / 2,
        pixmap.getHeight() / 2,
        0,
        GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE,
        GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        /* buffer V */);

GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indicesBuffer);
```

What do I miss?

**EDIT:** Frames are provided from two different decoders and all works find with an other render process.

**EDIT2:** I displayed only the Y plane and the result is a grey frame (as expected) but there is no hatch lines!!

[image]

I just replaced these lines in my fragment shader to display it:

```
" r = texture2D(yTexture, vTexCoord).r;\n" +
" g = texture2D(yTexture, vTexCoord).g;\n" +
" b = texture2D(yTexture, vTexCoord).b;\n" +
```

So problem comes from U/V planes?

Comment: What is the size of pixmap?

Comment: @Unick I just haded this precision: it's a 1080x607 pixmap. I display it on a 1080x1776 screen using a matrix projection to get it center with the original aspect ratio (with or without this matrix, I've got hatch).

Comment: Try to use gles20.GL_NEAREST for your textures, i think you no need interpolation for YUV textures.

Comment: @Unick You mean for `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` and `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER`? Sorry but it produces the same result...

Comment: Yes, MIN_FILTER and MAG_FILTER. Maybe the problem is in odd height. Because you decided it to 2. (pixmap.getHeight() / 2). What happens if you will use frame with even size? What YUV format do you use? NV12, I420?

Comment: @Unick I tried with a 1794x1080 pixmap in my 1794x1080 screen (same size and pair). Nothing changed. I use YUV420P (and it is, I verified it). Bigger are the frame, more are the lines. With smaller frames, (640x360), there is no line visible!

Comment: I think you have correct result for Y plane, but you have problem in U or V plane. Could please make 3 screenshot for each plane? I can help to find where is bug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130610/discussion-between-n0un-and-unick).

Comment: When you get a decoded frame in YUV format it will have a width as well as a linesize. Could you be using the width of the frame in your texture data instead of the linesize? I compensate for the overscan ffmpeg gives by adjusting the texture coordinates.